# Jersey REST Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readInt

Tags: java, rest, jersey, java-5

I am using Jersey 1.2 for building RESTful services using JDK1.5

When I test REST services, I am getting the following exception.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2884779   at
>       org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readInt(Unknown Source)   at
>       org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>       org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)    at 
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess
>       (AnnotationScannerListener.java:130)    at
>       com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.
>       f(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)    at 
>       com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:68)

I have created a simple class for testing

```
@Path("/employee")
public class TestRest {


    @GET
    @Produces( { MediaType.TEXT_HTML })
    public String getClichedMessage() {

        return "Hello Smith";
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

My jar versions

```
jersey-server-1.2.jar
jersey-core-1.2.jar
grizzly-servlet-webserver-1.9.18-i.jar
asm-3.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.jar
```

Comment: Why JDK1.5? That's ancient.

Comment: @LutzHorn For one of the legacy application server, we have JDK1.5, so  options are limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your annotation

```
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) also try
```

Also try

you are having an incorrect version of asm.jar on your classpath. Make sure:

your deployed lib folder contains the same jars as target/app.war/WEB-INF/lib

you don't have two versions of the asm.jar

you don't have conflicting versions in maven

Comment: You mean `MediaType.TEXT_HTML`, it didn't help.

Comment: Remove the flower bracket

Comment: Well your point of verifying whether I have conflicting versions made me think about conflicting jars and there was a spring mvc jar which was causing this issue even though  I am not using Maven for this project. I removed all unwanted and jars which are not being used, recompiled the project and tested again, it worked as expected. Thanks for your suggestion. By the way `@POST` is not relevant for ths, `@GET` is what required.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this code

```
@GET
@Path("/get_something")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Message<String> getSomething(@QueryParam("p_item") String p_item,  @QueryParam("p_items") List<String> p_items) throws Exception {
    ...
    p_items.forEach(s -> {
       try {
           // something that throws IOException 
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
    });
    ...
}
```

After I changed `forEach` to regular loop it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was using apache server 8.5.59 and getting same exception.
Now I moved to apacher server version 8.5.12.

It is working fine.

Please find jar details

- asm-3.1.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.1.5.1.jar

JDK : Zulu 8.36.0.2

Eclipse : Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Some pom dependencies can cause this problem.Remove last added dependencies and try again.When i add log4j dependencies to my pom.xml i had this error.I removed and it solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75930224/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand how you encountered this issue and how you were able to resolve it. I recommend you visit [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and take some inspiration from how the other answers provided some context surrounding their encounter with this issue, so their solutions made more sense